# Rename tag request: vibram-five-fingers

Tags: discussion, tags

I believe that the tag [vibram-five-fingers](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vibram-five-fingers) should be renamed to [vibram-fivefingers](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vibram-fivefingers) as FiveFingers is the official name of the product.  Also, I recommend making `fivefingers` a synonym.

Comment: Is anyone actually doing anything about this? Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Liam The moderators are all absent.

Comment: Absent? As in temporarily away or not moderating any more?

Comment: @Liam I meant only as in they are probably *outdoors* the last couple of days.  I do note that two of the moderators haven't bothered to visit **meta** in some while though, as you can see [here](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: @Liam Just because we don't act doesn't mean we don't see.

Comment: Since Vibram and FiveFingers are both brand names, but there are many competing products, would it not be better to rename it altogether to *toe-sandals* or *minimalist-footwear* some such?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure about this. I understand that the official spelling is FiveFingers, but the CamelCase distinguishes the two words in it. Since we don't have uppercase letters in tags, I think five-fingers is more clear.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I want to put @choster´s comment as a votable answer here, because I find it very important:

We should not rename the tag, but delete it! It´s a product name, do you want to get a tag for every product (or even for every toe-sandal)? I think we should, at least in tags, stay absolutely neutral. So we delete product names and put, in replacement for [five-fingers](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/five-fingers), create/use the tag [toe-sandals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toe-sandals). We can still create a synonym for it, so the individual products get connected to this tag.

Comment: In principle I agree, but in practice I see this a problematic.  I'd never heard of "toe sandals" before choster's comment.  Vibram FiveFingers were the first popular product, so that's what people call these; it's like Zipper or Velcro.  Nobody talks about a "linear interlocking-tooth closure" so finding discussion about that with a search engine isn't easy, when you are looking for Zipper.  Velcro is a softer example, and you *do* see ads describing "hook-and-loop closure" but again that's not what people usually call it in conversation, and Velcro is more recognizable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You got a point here. Still, I think most of the issues could be prevented by creating the brand or product name as a synonym to the "official tag". I don´t know how this would affect search engine results. 
Btw, whats Velcro?

Comment: I guess that's an Americanism.  What do *you* call [this stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velcro)?  (Actually I just read on that page that the company is based in The Netherlands.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Klettband. But thats german, I don´t know any english word for it ;) In the dictionary it says "hook-and-loop band" or "Velcro(R)"...